# How to convert row values with same index(one of the MultiIndex) into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem, 
the index of my dataframe is 2019-month-day(date) and the 0,1,2,3 (hourss)

my dataframe is like this:

```py
[In]
g = df3.groupby(['Date', 'hourss'], sort=False).screen_status.agg(['sum'])
#reset index 
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([g.index.levels[0], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
h = g.reindex(idx,fill_value=0)  
h

------------------------------------
[out]
                sum
-----------------------------
2019-08-30  0     0
            1     0
            2     0
            3     45
2019-08-31  0     62
            1     6
            2     0
            3     31
2019-09-01  0     6
            1     26
            2     110
            3     178
...
```

But I want to change the frame like:

```py
              0     1     2      3
---------------------------------------------
2019-08-30    0     0     0      45
2019-08-31    62    6     0      32
2019-09-01    6     26    110    178
```

Hope to get some advice.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `h.unstack()`

EDIT:
Just add at the end:

```
h = h.unstack()['sum']  # select sub dataframe 'sum'. In this way you won't have 'sum' as header.
h
```

Comment: omg! that's what I am looking for ! But it also has  "sum" above column name (1,2,3,4), can I remove it ?

Comment: Ah right, sorry I didn't think about it. I am updating my answer